# Fetch Value from key value pair Object

Tags: java

I have a object like keys value pair, but i am unable to fetch specific value.

```
Object obj="[{Branch=60, Currency=cv, Id=abv, RemainingAmount=20.45},{Branch=60, Currency=INJ, Id=bnb, RemainingAmount=120.0}]";
```

Comment: Can't you add it to a map with incrementing integer value?

Comment: I don't understand--you have a string that contains something that *looks* like an array of objects in invalid JSON.

Comment: @DaveNewton yes

Comment: @ManeeshaIndrachapa no

Comment: So what do you *actually* want to do?

Comment: @Dave Newton I want the value of Id,currency and save into a new list.

Comment: So you want to take the string's invalid JSON and pretend it's JSON-like? It's unclear what your actual usecase is--IRL if you had JSON (like from an API) you'd parse it as JSON. Here you're deliberately constructing a string that cannot be parsed as JSON--if you're constructing the string anyway why go through all this trouble? What aren't you telling us?